# Does electron travel in vaccum in a double slit experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

I don't have a physics/mathematics background; but I'm quite intrigued by Quantum physics.

I was wondering if someone could shed light on whether particles travel through a vaccum, some specific medium or just air in a double slit experiment.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Charged particles like electrons are strongly scattered by air molecules so in air their range is limited and they don't travel in straight lines. You could do a double slit experiment in air if you weren't too worried about the accuracy, but normally any electron diffraction experiments are done inside sealed equipment in a vacuum.